# Priority-Web-SDK btoa "Buffer is not defined"

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg, erp

I'm building a React Native application using create-react-native-app.  The app connects to Priority via the API without error, however when I need to use the Web-SDK to get the options for a choose field it is throwing an error:

```
SDK Error: ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
at btoa (C:\...\node_modules\btoa\index.js:8)
at b64encode (C:\...\node_modules\priority-web-sdk\index.js:2744)
at $FormQuery (C:\...\node_modules\priority-web-sdk\index.js:3898)
at $GetRows (C:\...\node_modules\priority-web-sdk\index.js:3957)
at Form_1.GetRows (C:\...\node_modules\priority-web-sdk\index.js:4673)
at C:\...\node_modules\priority-web-sdk\index.js:6234
at tryCallTwo (C:\...\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45)
at doResolve (C:\...\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200)
at new Promise (C:\...\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66)
at Object.gform.getRows (C:\...\node_modules\priority-web-sdk\index.js:6233)
```

**Actual files paths edited for brevity/privacy.

My code that calls getRows()

```
return login(configuration)
    .then(() => formStart('PORDERS', null, null, configuration.company, 1))
    .then(form => myForm = form)
    .then(() => myForm.setSearchFilter(filter))
    .then(() => myForm.getRows(1))
    .then(r => rows = r)
    .then(() => myForm.setActiveRow(1)) 
    .then(a => row = a)
    .then(() => myForm.choose('STATDES',rows.PORDERS[row.rowindex].STATDES))
    .then((response) => {return response.ChooseLine})
    .catch(err => console.log('SDK Error: ', err));
```

This issue popped up recently.  It was working fine before.  I thought maybe I had upgraded a package incorrectly, so I reverted to a previous version of the yarn.lock file and rebuilt the node_modules folder, but with no success.

I feel like this is more of a yarn/npm package or Priority issue than React-native, but I'm at a loss.  Any suggestions on what else I could do?

**Update:**
The more I work on this and the more I try different things, it feels to me more and more like an issue of my test setup having different native functions than my live set up.  Any suggestions on how to check/solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in version 1.9.3 of [priority-web-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/priority-web-sdk).

In addition, here is a link to Priority Master app's repository that is built with `react-native`: https://github.com/PrioritySoftware/priority-master-react.